# How to declare this variable

Tags: javascript, app-lab

I am working on a app using App Lab (code.org). I am sorry if this is a very easy fix. I started javascript just 3 months ago and this is my first project.

I want the countdown to start once they click button "start_city_game_button" however I am getting this error

```
setInterval() callback parameter value (1000) is not a function
```

and

```
setInterval() milisecond parameter value (undefined) is not a number.
```

These errors appear in line 2.

```
var city_time = 60;
var city_time_counter = setInterval(1000);

function cityTimer() {
city_time = city_time -1;
  clearInterval(city_time_counter);
  }
}
```

I expect the timer to start once level has been started, however the time actually starts when the app starts. I have gone through many drafts of this code to find the correct anwser but I cannot find the way.

```js
onEvent("back_mainscreen", "click", function() {
  setScreen("start_screen");
});
onEvent("instructions", "click", function() {
  setScreen("instructions");
});
onEvent("startgame", "click", function() {
  setScreen("city_screen");
});

// City Code
var city_tries = 0;
var city_time = 60;
var city_time_counter = setInterval(1000);



onEvent("start_game_city_button", "click",function() {
city_time = city_time -1;
console.log(city_time);
setText("second_city_time", city_time);
  if (city_time === 0) {
  setScreen("city_screen");
  clearInterval(city_time_counter);
  }
});
  
  onEvent("start_game_city_button", "click", function() {
  console.log("CONSOLE: Player Started City Level");
  console.log(city_tries);
  setScreen("city_game_screen");
  city_tries = city_tries + 1;
});




var score = 0;
onEvent("deer", "click", function() {
  setPosition("deer", randomNumber(50,240), randomNumber(50, 400));
  score = score + 1;
 setText("score_label", score);
});
// Ocean Code
var ocean_tries = 0;
onEvent("ocean_start_button", "click", function() {
    ocean_tries = ocean_tries + 1;
  console.log("CONSOLE: Player Started Ocean Level. Try");
    console.log(ocean_tries);
});
```

Comment: You aren't passing the function to be called to `setInterval`.

Comment: First argument needs to be the function: `setInterval(cityTimer, 1000)`

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for `setInterval`

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to `setInterval` is a function. And second parameter is amount of time.

```
var city_time_counter = setInterval(cityTimer,1000);
```

If you want the timer to start on click then attach a listener to the element and setInterval in that.

```
document.getElementById("start_city_game_button").addEventListener('click',()=>{
    city_time_counter = setInterval(1000);
})
```

And also if you need to decrease variable by `1` you can use a shorthand for that.

```
city_time = city_time -1;
```

The above line is same as

```
city_time--;
```

Comment: I need to define cityTimer. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: @pdxryanpdx Your question is clear what is **cityTimer**

Comment: cityTimer is a 60 second timer

Comment: @pdxryanpdx Then your code should work. If its not working then create a snippet to show the actual problem.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/895bc60c53d90c0cf74ca6e4649acc59 thats my code. If you want, I can add all my code but it is very messy

Comment: ^^ is this what you meant as a snippet?

Comment: @pdxryanpdx No. Go to edit and create a snippet using **<>** sign

Comment: added snippet :)

Comment: I think I did this correctly. Please confirm. Thanks -pdx

Comment: @pdxryanpdx What is `onEvent`. Are you creating this on a particular platform?

Comment: I am using Code.org's AppLab

Comment: @pdxryanpdx You didn't mentioned that anywhere in the post. Please read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Will do. However I did include that. First line

Comment: what would you like me to do?

Comment: @pdxryanpdx Give me link where I could see the non-working code and test it.

Comment: Here is the link https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/hPo0MX3e_e53KOIdkfpjE8MIqxAyoPdmh3UEYOpigxE